# Add another css grid container/div below the first one

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I've been learning css grid, and I've tried to make a common layout. In this layout I want to add another container/div (basically a sidebar) just below the first one, tinkering around with it, I've managed to get it to the second row however it appears at the very bottom. How can I have it starting just below the first container?

**Disclaimer: I'm only using bootstrap for some small stylings, I would prefer sticking to using css for the overall layout**

```css
.container {
  max-width: 1400px;
}

.text-gray {
  color: #c0c3c5;
}

.grid-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  gap: 10px;
}

.sidebar {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  align-self: start;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 12px 8px;
}

.sidebar-two {
  border: 1px solid #00639e;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}

.right-bar {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #fff;
  align-self: start;
}

.right-bar-two {
   grid-row: 2;
}

.content {
  grid-column: 2 / 4;
}

.content img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

.tags a {
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  font-family: "Noto Sans", sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.7;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  color: #1a1a1b;
}

.tags a:hover {
  transition: 250ms ease;
  color: #00639e;
}

.sub-title {
  font-family: "Noto Serif", serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: italic;
  letter-spacing: 0.3px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="grid-wrapper my-3">
    <div class="sidebar py-2">
      <h1 class="fw-bold text-gray fs-6">Sidebar Container 1</h1>
      <div class="tags d-flex flex-column">
        <a href="#">Hello World 1</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar-two py-2">
      <h1 class="fw-bold text-gray fs-6">Sidebar Container 2</h1>
      <div class="tags d-flex flex-column">
        <a href="#">This should be just below Sidebar Container 1</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="featured-image">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1507525428034-b723cf961d3e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1173&q=80" alt="Featured banner">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right-bar tags px-2 pt-1">
      <h1 class="fw-bold text-gray fs-6">Sidebar Container 3</h1>
      <a href="#">Hello World 2</a>
    </div>
    <div class="right-bar right-bar-two tags px-2 pt-1">
      <h1 class="fw-bold text-gray fs-6">Sidebar Container 4</h1>
      <a href="#">This should be just below Sidebar Container 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should really decide how you want to solve your layout. Either with Bootstrap which does not use CSS-Grid but Flexbox or with a real custom CSS-Grid. Depending on that, you also have different solutions. What shall it be for you? A solution with Bootstrap-Grid (Flexbox) or CSS-Grid? You should not mix both!

Comment: The layout is not yet completed, I'm just using bootstrap to play around with paddings, boldening text or coloring text and such. In terms of layout you can see I've not used any bootstrap

Comment: Bootstrap does offer CSS Grid: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/css-grid/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make it way simpler with Flexbox or Bootstrap-Grid. The easiest way with CSS-Grid is either using `grid-template-areas` or hardcode their position with `grid-column` to move inside the right column.

```css
.container {
  max-width: 1400px;
}

.text-gray {
  color: #c0c3c5;
}

.grid-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  gap: 10px;
}

.sidebar {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 12px 8px;
}

.right-bar {
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
}

/* selects all elements with a class that starts with sidebar and aligns them to the msot left column */
[class^="sidebar"] {
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
}

/* selects all elements that contain a class that starts with right-bar and aligns them to the most right column */
[class^="right-bar"] {
  grid-column: 4 / 5;
}

/* selects all classes that contain -two and places them to the 2nd row */
[class*="-two"] {
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}

.sidebar-two {
  border: 1px solid #00639e;
}

.right-bar {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #fff;
}

.content {
  grid-column: 2 / 4;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
}

.content img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

.tags a {
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  font-family: "Noto Sans", sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.7;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  color: #1a1a1b;
}

.tags a:hover {
  transition: 250ms ease;
  color: #00639e;
}

.sub-title {
  font-family: "Noto Serif", serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: italic;
  letter-spacing: 0.3px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="grid-wrapper my-3">
    <div class="sidebar py-2">
      <h1 class="fw-bold text-gray fs-6">Sidebar Container 1</h1>
      <div class="tags d-flex flex-column">
        <a href="#">Hello World 1</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar-two py-2">
      <h1 class="fw-bold text-gray fs-6">Sidebar Container 2</h1>
      <div class="tags d-flex flex-column">
        <a href="#">This should be just below Sidebar Container 1</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="featured-image">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1507525428034-b723cf961d3e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1173&q=80" alt="Featured banner">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right-bar tags px-2 pt-1">
      <h1 class="fw-bold text-gray fs-6">Sidebar Container 3</h1>
      <a href="#">Hello World 2</a>
    </div>
    <div class="right-bar-two tags px-2 pt-1">
      <h1 class="fw-bold text-gray fs-6">Sidebar Container 4</h1>
      <a href="#">This should be just below Sidebar Container 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can this be adjusted in a way that stops the containers from expanding *with* the content? e.g. In this case the height of the image has caused the containers to expand leaving a huge white space

Comment: yeah, you need to let the content then span all rows. I updated the snippet.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with either Bootstrap, Flexbox, or CSS grid.

**Here I used CSS grid**. Check following code:

```css
.container {
  max-width: 1400px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr;
}

.text-gray {
  color: #c0c3c5;
}

.sidebar > div {
  margin-right: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  align-self: start;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 12px 8px;
}

.right-bar > div {
  margin-left: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #fff;
  align-self: start;
}

.content img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

.tags a {
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  font-family: "Noto Sans", sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.7;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  color: #1a1a1b;
}

.tags a:hover {
  transition: 250ms ease;
  color: #00639e;
}

.sub-title {
  font-family: "Noto Serif", serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: italic;
  letter-spacing: 0.3px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <div class="py-2 md-2">
      <h1 class="fw-bold text-gray fs-6">Sidebar Container 1</h1>
      <div class="tags d-flex flex-column">
        <a href="#">Hello World 1</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="py-2 mt-2">
      <h1 class="fw-bold text-gray fs-6">Sidebar Container 2</h1>
      <div class="tags d-flex flex-column">
        <a href="#">This should be just below Sidebar Container 1</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="featured-image">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1507525428034-b723cf961d3e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1173&q=80" alt="Featured banner">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-bar">
    <div class="tags md-2 px-2 pt-1">
      <h1 class="fw-bold text-gray fs-6">Sidebar Container 3</h1>
      <a href="#">Hello World 2</a>
    </div>
    <div class="tags mt-2 px-2 pt-1">
      <h1 class="fw-bold text-gray fs-6">Sidebar Container 4</h1>
      <a href="#">This should be just below Sidebar Container 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm only looking for a css solution, not bootstrap. I'm using bootstrap only for some edits and stylings

Comment: Okay. thanks for pointing it out. I modified the code using CSS Grid, Please check the updated code.

Comment: What are "edits and stylings"? Why would you load an entire library and not use it?

Comment: Because it's just a simple layout, by edits and stylings I mean stuff like color or padding or margin. This isn't something that's going to production, it's me trying to understand how CSS Grid layout works, that's it.